# problemas al aplicar el patrón Model-View-Router (MVR) en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Buen dia, estoy tratando de aplicar el patron MVR en node para una practica.
la estructura de mi proyecto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al abrir la ruta http://localhost:3000/tasks/
me indica el siguiente error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined
    at C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\routes\tasks.js:4:15
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\NODEJS\mini-market\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

este es el contenido de mi modelo..

```
module.exports = app => {
    return {
        findAll: (params, callback) => {
            return callback([
                {title: "Buy some shoes"},
                {title: "Fix notebook"}
            ]);
        } 
    }
};
```

// la ruta

```
module.exports = app => {
    const Tasks = app.models.tasks;
    app.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {
        Tasks.findAll({}, (tasks) => {
            res.json({tasks: tasks});
        });
    });
};
```

// el index.js

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express');
var consing = require('consign');

const app = express();

app.set("json spaces", 4);

consing()
    .include("models")
    .then("libs/middlewares.js")
    .then("routes")
    .then("libs/boot.js")
    .into(app);
```

al parecer la funcion de findAll esta indefinida. alguna idea?

// package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mini market",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "consign": "^0.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.13"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por la estructura que definiste en `task.js` deberia ser:

```
module.exports = app => {
    const Tasks = app.models.task(app); //task es una funcion y te sobra una "s"
    app.get("/tasks", (req, res) => {
        Tasks.findAll({}, (tasks) => {
            res.json({tasks: tasks});
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: si me di cuenta que tenia una "s" de mas